# Ng-switch doesn't work inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

When i.typ is changed the ng-switch doesn't update in the below code. Maybe this has to do with the ng-repeat oustide the switch? On page reload it works but not when model is changed.

```
<div id="sceneCtrl" ng-controller="SceneController">

    <transform id="{{'annotation'+i.ID}}" ng-repeat="i in vm.sharedService.SceneAnnotations">
        <group ng-switch on="{{i.typ}}">
            <transform ng-switch-when="0" > [subtree 0...] </transform>
            <transform ng-switch-when="1" > [subtree 1...] </transform>
        </group>
    </transform>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the curly brackets from your `on="{{i.typ}}"`.

Try this instead:

```
<group ng-switch on="i.typ">
```

Answer (score 2):

I put together an example of what an ng-switch looks like inside of an ng-repeat. In order to make the example work I did replace your variables but the idea and syntax are exactly the same:

```
<div ng-repeat="player in myPlayers">
  <!-- just so you can see the repeat is working normally: -->
  Player: <span class="playername" ng-bind="player.name"></span>

  <!-- here is the switch: -->
  <div ng-switch on="player.gameRole">
    <div ng-switch-when="IT">YOU ARE IT</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="NOT IT">This player is NOT it</div>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
</div>
```

To see this live, look at a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0lbqKjlgo1Y8aLNMoGNs?p=preview

---

As to your other question of why the switch doesn't change when the value of a variable changes there are a few reasons this might happen. The most common reason is because you are in a directive or somewhere that "$scope.$apply()" isn't getting called for you. Add this line in and it should work (probably)!

Best of luck!